# Android, как разбудить Activity?

Tags: android, activity, android-intent

Ситуация такая: Активити (MainActivity) запускает сервис, после чего я нажимаю кнопку HOME. Активити находится в состоянии onStop, сервис работает. Когда сервис завершает работу, он создаёт уведомление, стандартное NewMessageNotification созданное из шаблона AndroidStudio. К этому уведомлению прикреплен интент:

```
notificationCompatBuilder.setContentIntent( 
PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, 
new Intent(context, MainActivity.class), 
PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT))
```

При нажатии на уведомление, открывается новое Активити (срабатывает событие onCreate), естественно пустое, без результатов работы сервиса. Затем жму кнопку Back, Активити закрывается, а под ним, сюрприз! Старая активити, отработала onPostResume и загрузила данные с результатами работы сервиса.

Вопрос: Как мне прописать интент таким образом, чтобы новая Активити не создавалась, а просыпалась старая?

Comment: Попробуйте в манифесте у активити прописать launch_mode="singleTop"

Comment: Ну вы же сами создаете новое меин активити вот оно и появляется, почему бы вам просто в этот интент не добавить результаты работы сервиса а так же добавить флаги для очистки стака активити 
setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
            | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

в манифесте у активити прописать launch_mode="singleTop"
Также можно использовать флаг для Intent:
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP) – аналогичен значению singleTop для launchMode.